# KafkaProducer InterruptedException during gracefull shutdown on spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

For a project we are sending some events to kafka. We use spring-kafka 2.6.2.

Due to usage of spring-vault we have to restart/kill the application before the end of credentials lease (application is automatically restarted by kubernetes).
Our problem is that when using **applicationContext.close()** to proceed with our gracefull shutdown, KafkaProducer gets an ***InterruptedException Interrupted while joining ioThread*** inside it's close() method.
It means that in our case some pending events are not sent to kafka before shutdown as it's forced to close due to an error during destroy.

Here under a stacktrace

```
2020-12-18 13:57:29.007  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete
2020-12-18 13:57:29.009  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-18 13:57:29.013  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-18 13:57:29.014  INFO [titan-producer,,,] 1 --- [tomcat-shutdown] o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown        : Graceful shutdown complete
2020-12-18 13:57:29.020  WARN [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [kafka-producer-network-thread | titan-producer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.9.1/sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:873)
 org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:469)
 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:544)
 org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
 org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2020-12-18 13:57:29.021  WARN [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [micrometer-kafka-metrics] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.9.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2020-12-18 13:57:29.046  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-18 13:57:29.048  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-12-18 13:57:29.051  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=titan-producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
2020-12-18 13:57:29.055 ERROR [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=titan-producer-1] Interrupted while joining ioThreadjava.lang.InterruptedException: null
        at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.join(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1205)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1182)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.closeDelegate(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:901)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.destroy(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:428)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:258)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1092)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1085)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1061)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:170)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:979)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:68)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)2020-12-18 13:57:29.055  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=titan-producer-1] Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 30000 ms.
2020-12-18 13:57:29.056  WARN [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'kafkaProducerFactory': org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
2020-12-18 13:57:29.064  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService
2020-12-18 13:57:29.065  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] c.l.t.p.zookeeper.ZookeeperManagerImpl   : Closing zookeeperConnection
2020-12-18 13:57:29.197  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Session: 0x30022348ba6000b closed
2020-12-18 13:57:29.197  INFO [titan-producer,,,] 1 --- [d-1-EventThread] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : EventThread shut down for session: 0x30022348ba6000b
2020-12-18 13:57:29.206  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : loadtest_fallback_titan_pendingEvents - Shutdown initiated...
2020-12-18 13:57:29.221  INFO [titan-producer,222efdd2a07966ce,222efdd2a07966ce,true] 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : loadtest_fallback_titan_pendingEvents - Shutdown completed.
```

Here is my configuration class

```
@Flogger
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        name = "titan.producer.kafka.enabled",
        havingValue = "true",
        matchIfMissing = true)
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer kafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        return producerFactory -> producerFactory.setValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<>(mapper));
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic createTopic(TitanProperties titanProperties, KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        TitanProperties.Kafka kafka = titanProperties.getKafka();
        String defaultTopic = kafkaProperties.getTemplate().getDefaultTopic();
        int numPartitions = kafka.getNumPartitions();
        short replicationFactor = kafka.getReplicationFactor();

        log.atInfo()
                .log("Creating Kafka Topic %s with %s partitions and %s replicationFactor", defaultTopic, numPartitions, replicationFactor);

        return TopicBuilder.name(defaultTopic)
                .partitions(numPartitions)
                .replicas(replicationFactor)
                .config(MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE_CONFIG, LOG_APPEND_TIME.name)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and my application.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: titan-producer

  kafka:
    client-id: ${spring.application.name}
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.UUIDSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

      properties:
        max.block.ms: 2000
        request.timeout.ms: 2000
        delivery.timeout.ms: 2000 #must be greater or equal to request.timeout.ms + linger.ms

    template:
      default-topic: titan-dev
```

Our vault configuration which executes the applicationContext.close() using a scheduledTask. We do it kind randomly as we have multiple replicas of the app running in parallel and avoid all the replicas to be killed at the same time.

```
@Flogger
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(SecretLeaseContainer.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        name = "titan.producer.scheduling.enabled",
        havingValue = "true",
        matchIfMissing = true)
public class VaultConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Lifecycle scheduledAppRestart(Clock clock, TitanProperties properties, TaskScheduler scheduler, ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        Instant now = clock.instant();
        Duration maxTTL = properties.getVaultConfig().getCredsMaxLease();
        Instant start = now.plusSeconds(maxTTL.dividedBy(2).toSeconds());
        Instant end = now.plusSeconds(maxTTL.minus(properties.getVaultConfig().getCredsMaxLeaseExpirationThreshold()).toSeconds());
        Instant randomInstant = randBetween(start, end);
        return new ScheduledLifecycle(scheduler, applicationContext::close, "application restart before lease expiration", randomInstant);
    }

    private Instant randBetween(Instant startInclusive, Instant endExclusive) {
        long startSeconds = startInclusive.getEpochSecond();
        long endSeconds = endExclusive.getEpochSecond();
        long random = RandomUtils.nextLong(startSeconds, endSeconds);

        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(random);
    }

}
```

The ScheduledLifecycle class we use to run the scheduledtasks

```
import lombok.extern.flogger.Flogger;
import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;

@Flogger
public class ScheduledLifecycle implements SmartLifecycle {
    private ScheduledFuture<?> future = null;
    private Duration delay = null;
    private final TaskScheduler scheduler;
    private final Runnable command;
    private final String commandDesc;
    private final Instant startTime;

    public ScheduledLifecycle(TaskScheduler scheduler, Runnable command, String commandDesc, Instant startTime) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        this.command = command;
        this.commandDesc = commandDesc;
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public ScheduledLifecycle(TaskScheduler scheduler, Runnable command, String commandDesc, Instant startTime, Duration delay) {
        this(scheduler, command, commandDesc, startTime);
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (delay != null) {
            log.atInfo().log("Scheduling %s: starting at %s, running every %s", commandDesc, startTime, delay);
            future = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(command, startTime, delay);
        } else {
            log.atInfo().log("Scheduling %s: execution at %s", commandDesc, startTime);
            future = scheduler.schedule(command, startTime);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (future != null) {
            log.atInfo().log("Stop %s", commandDesc);
            future.cancel(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        boolean running = future != null && (!future.isDone() && !future.isCancelled());
        log.atFine().log("is %s running? %s", running);
        return running;
    }
}
```

Is there a bug with spring-kafka? Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Edit the question to show your configuration. What is thread `scheduling-1` from? It looks like a task scheduler that is shut down (hard) before the producer factory is closed. You need to make sure that scheduler is shut down later.

Comment: Sorry I added a bit more configuration on the post. This scheduling-1 seems to come from the SchedulingLifecycle class I mentionned. We execute the applicationContext.close() through it using scheduledTasks. I'll investigate this way as it looks linked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`future.cancel(true);`

This is interrupting the producer thread and is likely the root cause of the problem.

You should use `future.cancel(false);` to allow the task to terminate in an orderly fashion, without interruption.

```java
    /**
     * Attempts to cancel execution of this task.  This attempt will
     * fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled,
     * or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful,
     * and this task has not started when {@code cancel} is called,
     * this task should never run.  If the task has already started,
     * then the {@code mayInterruptIfRunning} parameter determines
     * whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in
     * an attempt to stop the task.
     *
     * <p>After this method returns, subsequent calls to {@link #isDone} will
     * always return {@code true}.  Subsequent calls to {@link #isCancelled}
     * will always return {@code true} if this method returned {@code true}.
     *
     * @param mayInterruptIfRunning {@code true} if the thread executing this
     * task should be interrupted; otherwise, in-progress tasks are allowed
     * to complete
     * @return {@code false} if the task could not be cancelled,
     * typically because it has already completed normally;
     * {@code true} otherwise
     */
    boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning);
```

**EDIT**

In addition, the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` is false by default.

```java
    /**
     * Set whether to wait for scheduled tasks to complete on shutdown,
     * not interrupting running tasks and executing all tasks in the queue.
     * <p>Default is "false", shutting down immediately through interrupting
     * ongoing tasks and clearing the queue. Switch this flag to "true" if you
     * prefer fully completed tasks at the expense of a longer shutdown phase.
     * <p>Note that Spring's container shutdown continues while ongoing tasks
     * are being completed. If you want this executor to block and wait for the
     * termination of tasks before the rest of the container continues to shut
     * down - e.g. in order to keep up other resources that your tasks may need -,
     * set the {@link #setAwaitTerminationSeconds "awaitTerminationSeconds"}
     * property instead of or in addition to this property.
     * @see java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#shutdown()
     * @see java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#shutdownNow()
     */
    public void setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(boolean waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown) {
        this.waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown = waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown;
    }
```

You might also have to set `awaitTerminationSeconds`.

Comment: Did it, I noticed that when I edited my post, but I continue to have the same behaviour.

Comment: Something else must be interrupting the thread then. You didn't show your `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` bean. You need to set its `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` property to true - see `shutdown()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the autoconfigured bean for ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, creating a bean and setting waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown and setAwaitTerminationSeconds did the job.